# url rewriting is not working in yetanotherforums

Tags: .net, yetanotherforum

I am downloading yetanoherforum open source and install the application 
but url rewriting  is not working ..

pls give me any ideas how to work url rewriting in yetanotherforums

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable urlrewriting. In your YAF Root, You have a file named: app.config. 
Open it and look for:  
change the value to true and you're good to go.